# Eclipse CodeLense

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, eclipse-plugin

Is there any Eclipse plugin that gives me the features of the CodeLense like in Visual Stuido (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx)

The coolest feature would be this:

[image: Method references]

Something like that, or similar Plugins that can do anything like that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean call hierarchy?

Comment: Yes but on top of the Method. So I can see how many times this Method is called. Call hierachy is the function but I want a "new" way to display it. If you know what I mean.